# Struggling With .htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would really appreciate a little help as I have been banging my head against a wall for the last few hours trying to create a `.htaccess RewriteRule`.

I have around 300 *URLs* that I need to 301 redirect following a site re-build, they are in groups of similar urls but infortunately not broken down in to folders.

Here is an example of a few *URLs*:-

```
https://www.domain.co.uk/chamaecyparis-lawsoniana-ellwoodii_2.htm
https://www.domain.co.uk/chamaecyparis-lawsoniana-ellwoodii-200225cm-6670.htm
https://www.domain.co.uk/chamaecyparis-lawsoniana-ellwoodii.htm
https://www.domain.co.uk/chamaecyparis-lawsoniana-ellwoods-gold.htm
https://www.domain.co.uk/chamaecyparis-lawsoniana-lemon-queen.htm
https://www.domain.co.uk/chamaecyparis-lawsoniana-yvonne-200cm-66.htm
```

All of the above *URLs* need to redirect to a new *URL*:-

http://www.domain.co.uk/chamaecyparis-lawsoniana

Here is the `RewriteRule` that I currently have but it isn't working:-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)_chamaecyparis-lawsoniana$ https://www.domain.co.uk/chamaecyparis-lawsoniana [R=301,L]
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks
:-)

Comment: Found the solution.     RewriteRule ^chamaecyparis-lawsoniana-.+ https://www.domain.co.uk/chamaecyparis-lawsoniana [R=301,L]

Comment: You should put that down as an answer and accept it so that the question is marked accordingly.